# OpenCV Python remove object/pattern from images

Tags: python, opencv, templates, design-patterns

I have been facing this problem from some days:
i need to remove  [this image/pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmOet.jpg) from images like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaxMZ.jpg) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOKbQ.jpg) using OpenCV.
I know that the problem is a Template Matching problem and I have to use filters (like canny) and and "slide" the template over the image, once this has been transformed by the filters.

I tried some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68089067/opencv-python-remove-certain-objects-in-an-image) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132149/how-to-remove-specific-tag-sticker-object-from-images-using-opencv), but i had poor results, for example applying the second method I obtain this images
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wbNG.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLzMR.png)

this is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Resizes a image and maintains aspect ratio
def maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    # Grab the image size and initialize dimensions
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    # Return original image if no need to resize
    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    # We are resizing height if width is none
    if width is None:
        # Calculate the ratio of the height and construct the dimensions
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    # We are resizing width if height is none
    else:
        # Calculate the ratio of the 0idth and construct the dimensions
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    # Return the resized image
    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)

# Load template, convert to grayscale, perform canny edge detection
template = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\Quirino\Desktop\Reti\Bounding_box\Checkboard.jpg')
template = cv2.resize(template, (640,480))
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
(tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
# cv2.imshow("template", template)

# Load original image, convert to grayscale
original_image = cv2.imread('F:\\ARCHAIDE\Appearance\Data_Archaide_Complete\MTL_G6\MTL_G6_MMO090.jpg')
# original_image = cv2.resize(original_image, (640,480))
final = original_image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
found = None

# Dynamically rescale image for better template matching
for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:

    # Resize image to scale and keep track of ratio
    resized = maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(gray, width=int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
    r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

    # Stop if template image size is larger than resized image
    if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
        break

    # Detect edges in resized image and apply template matching
    canny = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
    detected = cv2.matchTemplate(canny, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    (_, max_val, _, max_loc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(detected)

    # Uncomment this section for visualization
    '''
    clone = np.dstack([canny, canny, canny])
    cv2.rectangle(clone, (max_loc[0], max_loc[1]), (max_loc[0] + tW, max_loc[1] + tH), (0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('visualize', clone)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    '''
    # Keep track of correlation value
    # Higher correlation means better match
    if found is None or max_val > found[0]:
        found = (max_val, max_loc, r)

# Compute coordinates of bounding box
(_, max_loc, r) = found
(start_x, start_y) = (int(max_loc[0] * r), int(max_loc[1] * r))
(end_x, end_y) = (int((max_loc[0] + tW) * r), int((max_loc[1] + tH) * r))

original_image = cv2.resize(original_image, (640,480))
# Draw bounding box on ROI to remove
cv2.rectangle(original_image, (start_x, start_y), (end_x, end_y), (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('detected', original_image)

# Erase unwanted ROI (Fill ROI with white)
cv2.rectangle(final, (start_x, start_y), (end_x, end_y), (255,255,255), -1)
final = cv2.resize(final, (640,480))
cv2.imshow('final', final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

what could i try?

***20230207 EDIT*

I tried the method below and it works great in the 80% of the images, but in some cases it doesn't recognize well the chess box and masks something else, for example you can see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otTFn.jpg) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4sWQ.jpg) and in other cases the chess box is recognized and covered only partially, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkIU7.jpg)

Comment: You could try a rotation invariant method [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/feature-matching-using-orb-algorithm-in-python-opencv/)

Comment: Just threshold on the white outer area. Then get the external contour. Then replace with whatever color you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to approach that in Python/OpenCV

- Read the input
- Threshold on the outer white region of the checkerboard pattern using cv2.inRange()
- Get the external contours and keep the largest
- Get the bounding box of the largest contour
- Get the color just outside the 4 corners of the bounding box and get its average
- Replace the bounding box region in a copy of the input with the average color
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('checks_object.jpg')

# threshold on outer white area of checkerboard pattern
lower = (210,210,210)
upper = (255,255,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# get external contours and keep largest
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# get bounding box of big contour
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour)

# get the average color of the 4 pixels just outside of the bounding box corners
[[color1]] = img[y-1:y, x-1:x]
[[color2]] = img[y-1:y, x+w:x+w+1]
[[color3]] = img[y+h:y+h+1, x+w:x+w+1]
[[color4]] = img[y+h:y+h+1, x-1:x]

ave_color = (color1.astype(np.float32) + color2.astype(np.float32) + color3.astype(np.float32) + color4.astype(np.float32)) / 4
ave_color = ave_color.astype(np.uint8)
print(ave_color)

# fill color inside contour bounding box
result = img.copy()
result[y:y+h, x:x+w] = ave_color

# save results
cv2.imwrite('checks_object_color_filled.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('checks_color_filled', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I tried you method and works great with about the 80% of the images, but in some cases it doesn't recognize well the white box and masks something else, I'll show below an example

Comment: You likely need to adjust the threshold values. If the image is too noisy and/or you have other white areas, then what you say might happen